# Binding data to existing number of elements based on object property

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 100 `<rect>` elements that I'm trying to select and modify using D3 based on the data objects' properties.

For example:

```
[Object, Object]
    0: Object
        name: "john"
        count: 32
    1: Object
        name: "jane"
        count: 48
```

I basically want to do some version of:

```
d3.selectAll(rect)
    .data(data)
    .attr('class', function(d) { return d.name });
```

…such that the first 32 `<rect>`s have the `class="john"`, the next 48 `<rect>`s have `class="jane"`, and the remaining 20 `<rect>`s have no class.

Right now it just classifies based on the number of objects — i.e., the first `<rect>` has `class="john"`, the second has `class="jane"`, and the other 98 don't have classes, but I can't figure out how to achieve the desired behavior here...

Comment: How are you creating the `rect`s and the data?

Comment: The `rect`s are being drawn through a separate function that executes first to create the 100 squares... the data is stored in a `var data` variable

Comment: My point is, why don't you have the correct name attributes everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way would probably be to add this class info when you create your `<rects>`.  But if for whatever reason your setup doesn't allow you to, then you should have an array with the same number of elements as the number of `<rects>` that you have.  `.data()` acts on all elements in an array, and each of those `<rects>` (in your case) inherits the information contained within each of the elements in the array:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#Data

Right now, when you execute your second code block, you are only updating to 2 `<rects>` because your array only contains 2 objects.  What you could do then is create another array that has the total 100 elements, each with the class that you want :)

Let me know if you have any other questions!